# Non repetitive random number generator in c

Tags: random, non-repetitive

I want to make a program that will give me 4 random numbers in the range 1 - 20 without any of them being the same. It does give me 4 different random numbers but every couple of tries 2 numbers are the same. I don't want that.
Here's my code:

```
int main(){
int g;
srand(time(0));
start:;
scanf("%d",&g);
switch(g){
case 1:RNG_4_10();
break;
default:exit(0);
break;
}
goto start;
}

int RNG_4_10(){

int a,n,i,c;
for(c=0;c<10;c++){
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        a = (rand() % 20 + 1);      //give a random value to a;
        n = a;                      //assign n the value of a;
        while(a == n){
        a = rand() % 20 + 1;                  
        }
        printf("%d\t",a);
}
}
}
```

Also, I know that RNG's have a probability of repeating numbers and in theory they could generate the same number for infinity, but what I don't get is how can I have 2 similar numbers on the same run. I added that `while` to avoid that. Is this code wrong or my understanding is awful?

Answer (score 2):

Most random number generators will have a probability of repeating values.   If they didn't their behaviour would be less random by various measures.

If you want four random values in the range 1-20, then create an array of 20 elements with all those values, and shuffle it with the help of your random number generator.   Then pick the first four values.

A common technique to shuffle is (in pseudocode)

```
 /*  shuffle an array of n elements */

 for (i = n-1; i > 0; --i)
 {
      swap(array[i], array[gen(n)]);   /*  zero-based array indexing */
 }
```

where `gen(n)` returns a suitably random value with values between `0` and `n-1`, possibly with repetition.

Comment: For just four numbers, you don't have to shuffle the whole 20 element array, just the first four positions.

Comment: Not true rossum.   That will not achieve the OP's requirement of picking 4 values from a set of 20.   Shuffling only the first four means that every set pick will contain the same set of four values, not four from a possible twenty.

Comment: You are swapping a random pick from anywhere in the array `gen(n)` into each of of the first four positions: i = 3, 2, 1, 0.  That is sufficient.  This is standard for the Fisher-Yates shuffle.